# How to provide command line arguments using HTTP under Node

Tags: node.js, http, command-line-arguments

Is it possible to pass command line arguments using HTTP under Node.js?  This seems like a simple thing to do but I can not seem to find out how or if it is even possible.   I am struggling a little with the async nature of node so may be missing something fundamental here!

Thanks,
Will

Comment: HTTP and command line are really quite different things. Are you asking for a way to pass parameters to your code via HTTP or are you running a node script from the command line on a local machine?

Comment: The former...I found all kinds of references for the latter.  I think I may be barking up the wrong tree.  What I guess I really want to do is pass parameters between several node.js scripts behind their corresponding forms.  Command line parameters being one way...some more eloquent, but unknown to me, node.js construct being another!

Comment: So you have several node.js scripts that are called by HTTP in some series and you want to pass info from one to the next?

Comment: Your questions led me to look at my problem again and I found a solution.  I have a Node.js script that presents a web page using http (script1).   Based on a user action another web page is generated and another script (script2) will be invoked to process that web page.   I would like some parameters passed between script1 and script2.  These scripts are actually modules called from a central bit of code so I can easily pass an object between them.  My solution does not feel very eloquent though...but I am wandering through the dark here in regards to Node.js.

Comment: This is the age old problem of stateless web pages. I'll post some ideas in an answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few choices of how to pass state info from one script to another. One of the simplest and most portable has been around since the beginning - when you get the user data posted from page1, send it along in hidden form elements of page2. Then a post of page2 will have the user input on the new form elements and **automatically include** the hidden form element values as well. Of course you can use the data in the page1 post to otherwise determine what goes on page2. And so on to page3, etc.

The other common choice is cookies. You leave a cookie on the user's browser when they view page1 and then query the browser for it in your code for page2. This is totally portable in modern browsers, but the user can turn off cookies and then it won't work.

Another option is session variables in your node.js scripts. These are pretty easy to work with, but some servers use cookies behind the scenes and they could be off. You might want to read up on that one.

None of those 3 *require* use of JavaScript on the browser which is required for the Ajax option. In this single page mode you can keep all the state info you want in the JavaScript code because the page never gets reloaded. That gets a little tougher for a beginner and there's also the possibility that Javascript is off. If you are developing a rich, interactive  app, you can expect your users to have JS enabled. But for a website with a few pages to sequence to casual visitors it may not always be on.

So, I'd suggest you try the hidden form elements to get started. Something like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="whatever" value="data-from-page1-post" />
```

If you put that onto a form in page2, it will come back in the post.

Have fun...

Comment: Somewhat ironic but I had considered writing something into the form but discounted the idea thinking that there might be a better way of doing it!   I want to avoid the cookie and session variable approach so am going to take your suggestion and use hidden form elements.   The other irony is, and this may mean nothing to you, but this is similar to a technique that I used when developing software in CICS for a mainframe several life times ago.